# Why $f$ is onto?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuosly differentiable function from $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\| f(x) - f(y) \| \geq \| x - y \|$. Then show that $f$ is onto?

I can prove that $f$ is not bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (using the above inequality), but I cannot handle the case where $f$ may have a one-sided bound in any variable (like $[a, \infty] \times [b, \infty] \times \cdots)$. For that I suspect, I have to work in $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ via projection and make use of continuous differentiable, but I have no concrete idea in my mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints: 1. Show $Df(x)$ has full rank everywhere. Conclude that $f(\mathbb R^n)$ is open by the inverse function theorem.

2. Show $f(\mathbb R^n)$ is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $Df(x)(v)=0$ and $\|v\|=1$, this implies that $f(x+tv)=f(x)+Df(x)(v)+0(t)=f(x)+0(t)$. You deduce that there exists $c>0$ such that $|t|<c$ implies that ${{\|f(x+tv)-f(x)\|}\over {|t|}}<{1\over 2}$. Contradiction, since $\|x+tv-x\|=|t|$ implies that $\|f(x+tv)-f(x)\|<{1\over 2}\|(x+tv)-x\|$
this implies that $Df(x)$ is invertible and the local inversion theorem implies that $f$ is open.

Let $y$ in the closure of the image of $f$, $y=\lim_nf(x_n)$, this implies that $f(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, since $\|f(x_n)-f(x_m)\|\geq \|x_n-x_m\|$, we deduce that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence and converges.